# CSS Stylesheet not being applied to html, but is loaded

Tags: html, css, apache, debian, webserver

I decided to test my webserver and it's working, but CSS is not being applied. I can see in my browser, that files are loaded, but they're not effecting html. CSS is also working fine, if I make  tag in head, and defines color: red; there. You can check the site by yourself: http://worldsmp.net/index.html

[DevTools Sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM6iL.png)

[DevTools Computed Body Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmJOO.png)

[Server Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khlyl.png)

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    hi
</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```css
body {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, best practices are to always set the path to files from the root directory of your project.

So, try changing:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

To:

```
<link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```